# Why XAMPP listens on wrong IP address?

Tags: mamp

I have a problem with fresh installation of XAMPP. It listens on my local IP address 192.168.64.2 instead of local host 127.0.0.1

[image]

Where can i change this so that it listens on my localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you installed the XAMPP VM version that executes a virtual machine on macOS. Check on the XAMPP website and download the normal version. Hope this is the case and that this info helps.